# Wireless does not work on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu

I install the Ubuntu 9.04 my old Lenovo Y520 laptop, the wirless does not work.My Wireless card is Intel Pro/wireless 2100 card. But I can not enable it. My wired card is working well. Does anyone meet it before.

the ifconfig output is

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:e4:5f:6c:30  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:574701 (574.7 KB)  TX bytes:169249 (169.2 KB)
          Interrupt:10 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:f1:58:79:b5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0x8000 Memory:d0202000-d0202fff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)
```

the output of iwconfig is

```
eth1      unassociated  ESSID:off/any  Nickname:"ipw2100"
          Mode:Managed  Channel=0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power:off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I have another question. When my OS is 9.04, there is a icon about network connection on the panel at the top. After I upgraded to 9.10, that icon disappeared. How can I get that back?

Best Regareds,

Comment: What does not work? Could you please post the output of `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`?

Comment: you might want to check ubuntu forums,I'm sure they can help you with your wireless problems

Comment: So are you running 9.04 or 9.10 now?

Comment: At first I install the 9.04,then Upgrade it to 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the Intel Wireless Firmware. Intel used to be pretty draconian about distributing it unless you did accepted the click-through license on Intel's website. This may have changed, but I forget when.

(It's why I went with Realtek & Ralink chipsets.)

it goes in `/bin/firmware` I think.

You can find the Intel Firmware here: http://ipw2100.sourceforge.net/firmware.php

Comment: Do you mean I need run the firmware?Sorry I do not quite catch you.

Comment: No. The driver will load the firmware. You just need to have it present.

Comment: so, what should I do now? I am new for it

Comment: http://ipw2100.sourceforge.net/firmware.php